# springloaded with Gradle, Groovy and spring-boot fails with java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: classCache

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, gradle, spring-boot, spring-loaded

I've successfully setup a spring-boot-groovytemplates and actuator project. 
However, when adding springloaded to buildscript/dependencies block, I get the following stracktrace when recompiling in IDEA

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: classCache
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1918)
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.SpringPlugin.clearCachedIntrospectionResults(SpringPlugin.java:162)
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.SpringPlugin.reloadEvent(SpringPlugin.java:127)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.fireReloadEvent(TypeRegistry.java:1767)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ReloadableType.loadNewVersion(ReloadableType.java:405)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.loadNewVersion(TypeRegistry.java:845)
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.ReloadableFileChangeListener.fileChanged(ReloadableFileChangeListener.java:51)
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.Watcher.determineChangesSince(FileSystemWatcher.java:235)
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.Watcher.run(FileSystemWatcher.java:219)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Any clues?

Comment: Wrong version of JDK? You probably need 1.7 for Spring Loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mention which versions of Spring Framework or Spring Loaded you're using, but I would guess that you're trying to use Spring Loaded 1.2.0 with Spring Framework 4.1. It looks like you've hit [this bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded/issues/80) in Spring Loaded. You should upgrade to Spring Loaded 1.2.1 as it contains [a change](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded/commit/b98a6caa705f502f593f2813f07bb9395dd4cd64) that fixes the problem and makes it compatible with Spring Framework 4.1.